# Jquery Ajax get method not working with PhoneGap

Tags: ajax, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Hello am creating an app that uses jquery ajax get method to receive data from a text file to use for my app, its working great in the browser but when export my app to android using PhoneGap the text is not displaying. But the rest of the app has loaded now i assume this is because something went wrong. Am new to PhoneGap can anyone assist me this is my code.

```js
// Ajax code that recieve data from text file
$.get('/info/animal.txt',function(data){
    var lines = data.split("~");
```

Comment: Where is animal.txt located? Is it in cordova_project/www/info ?

Comment: The animal. txt is located in my project folder in the www folder.. the file is in the right place because it works fine when i use the phone gap desktop app but when i build the app using build.phonegap it doesn't work